# ifelse with saving objects doesn't work

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, model

I will create a loop which creates a model. The model with the highest value should be use later,

```
d <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:100){

  model <- lm(...)

  d <- rbind(d,model_result)

  # here the results should be saved

  # if the model_result is higher than the highest before (in data frame "d") it 
  should be saved, so that i can use it later.


  ifelse(model_result > max(d$V1), saveRDS(model,file = "mymodel.rds"), "")
}

model <- readRDS("mymodel.rds")
```

the saving works, but not only by the highest value will be saved rather then EVERY Value, so the model which is savest is always the latest in loop and not the highest.

I still tried other if-else functions but no one works.

Comment: `ifelse` is designed for use on vectors. You might want to use `if` instead. `if(model_result > max(d$V1)) saveRDS(model,file = "mymodel.rds")` should work. On the other hand, you could also just keep the best model in memory and the write out the single best model as soon as the loop exits. like `if(model_result > max(d$V1)) best_model <- model`.

Comment: i try both and with if() r doesn't will write a file (save the file), i really don't know why. *I already had checked the workpath

Answer (score 0):

Please use `if()` over `ifelse()` for the above purpose